# Stop Gmail's chat from updating status automatically?

Tags: gmail

It really annoys me that whenever I move my mouse to the gmail window to reply to an email, my status in chat becomes available automatically. Gmail provides no way to disable this default behaviour. So I am thinking to write a greasemonkey script to disable this. Basically, I am thinking to enable this only when my mouse is moved into the chat frame or I am currently chatting. But I only have limited knowledge of javascript and gmail.

So is this gonna be very hard to do? or any hints on how this could be done?

Thank you!

Comment: As you've limited knowledge of Javascript, I recommend you to request such a script on [Userscripts forum: Ideas and script requests](http://userscripts.org/forums/2).

Comment: thanks, I will put a request there. But at the same time, I am still interested to know how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to use the GTalk program instead of the GMail build in solution.

You can also access the GTalk protocol (Jabber) with any major messenger
http://www.google.com/support/chat/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=24670

These messengers have the option to control when switching from busy to available.

Comment: yeah, of course, a standalone messenger would have full control of this.